# Are there any darkweb stores running ethereum?

Tags: darkweb

First, I don't support sale of illicit items.  Having said that, wouldn't the implementation of ethereum on the darkweb prevent the host from running off with the funds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's https://github.com/SafeMarket/dapp

It's still in pretty early alpha, but it works and has an interesting sub-market model, kind of like subreddits.

Answer (score 8):

> Having said that, wouldn't the implementation of ethereum on the darkweb prevent the host from running off with the funds?

Theoretically, you can use multisig to make a dark market even on bitcoin that is decentralized and doesn't have the host problem. However, the tooling around ethereum is at this point substantially more advanced so it would definitely be easy to code such functionality. You can probably also do cool stuff around zero-knowledge proofs or linkable ring signatures on top of blockchain-based KYC schemes (surprisingly enough) to limit the number of (still securely pseudonymous) accounts that users can create and thereby reduce the incidence of scams as reputation can actually go negative if you do something really bad and you actually can't just create a new account.